# CSS: Change section size

Tags: css, size, padding, margin, sections

I have a problem with my webpage, there´s a huge gap between my last section and my call to action. How could you solve it?
Thanks for the support!

This the HTml for the certificate section. I think the problem is in CSS but i think the reference will be better if i add th HTML.

```
<section class="certificado">
<h1>Nuestras certificaciones</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="certificado-col">
        <img src="fotos/certificado_ISO.jpg" id="ISO">
        <div>
             <h4><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>Estamos certificados con el sistema<br><h4/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

This is the section for the call to action, it works just fine.

```
<section class = "cta">
    <h1>Nos encantaría trabajar contigo</h1>
         <a href="" class="hero-btn">Cotiza tu proyecto con nosotros</a>
</section>
```

This is the CSS, where the magic should happen. But it makes a huge gap between the last section and the call to action.

```
.certificado{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    display: auto;
}
.certificado-col{
    flex-basis: 10%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px;
    cursor: default;
    display: flex;
  
}
.certificado-col img{
   height: 50%;
   width: auto;
   border-radius: 20%;
   
}
.certificado-col p{
    padding: 0;
}
.certificado-col h3{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Here´s the section for the call to action. It works perfect but it´s too far away from the last section, maybe the problem could be here.

```
.cta{
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(fotos/closing\ deal.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0;
}
.cta h1{
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .cta h1{
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}
```

This is the image of the gap looks between the two sections
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/288hL.jpg)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the big gap just comes from all the `<br>` tags and the padding of the 'call to action' section. Is this what you mean?

Comment: My mistake, that´s from the original code but it has nothing to do with the gap. I´ll post an image so you know how it looks.

Comment: The image has been uploaded. Thank´s for pointing me the issue with the question Logan! :D

Comment: No problem :) it's hard to know what the issue is without a complete section of code where I can reprodoce your problem. My first thought is the size of your image but not sure. Is it possible the image you're using has a large portion of whitespace?

Comment: The size of my image it´s quite big but its smaller thanks to the css. And youré right, maybe a copy of the complete code would help. But it´s a lot of text for this question only. Do you mind if i send it to you through your personal profile?

Comment: Is it possible to have a copy of your code in the question that is striped of all the text and is just the html tags in question? I don't thinik a really long paste is too big of a concern. You can send the code if you want through my personal profile though, I don't mind.

Comment: Perfect bro! I´ll send it to you in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser's Developer Tools is a handy tool to use. It shows the space between the two sections is made up of padding in `div.certificado-col` and a top margin on `section.cta`.

[image]

[image]

Is the spacing sufficient if you remove the 100px of block margin from "cta"?

(before/after)

```
.cta {
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.cta {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
.certificado{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    display: auto;
}
.certificado-col{
    flex-basis: 10%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px;
    cursor: default;
    display: flex;
  
}
.certificado-col img{
   height: 50%;
   width: auto;
   border-radius: 20%;
   
}
.certificado-col p{
    padding: 0;
}
.certificado-col h3{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

.cta{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(fotos/closing\ deal.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0;
}
.cta h1{
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .cta h1{
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="certificado">
<h1>Nuestras certificaciones</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="certificado-col">
        <img src="fotos/certificado_ISO.jpg" id="ISO">
        <div>
             <h4><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>Estamos certificados con el sistema<br></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class = "cta">
    <h1>Nos encantaría trabajar contigo</h1>
         <a href="" class="hero-btn">Cotiza tu proyecto con nosotros</a>
</section>
```

Comment: OMG YES! THATS IT! thank you so much